# Xcode 4: Missing File's Owner with Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uiapplicationdelegate

I started a new project under Xcode 4.5. I accepted the default wizard settings, which included a storyboard.

I went to make connections and the File's Owner is missing.

I'm not sure what I did to end up in this configuration. As far as UI components, I added a scroll view in place of the original view. I had some trouble with Vertical Constraints, but I did not do anything drastic.

I tried to Google for the issue, but only got back two results: http://www.google.com/#q=xcode+4+%22missing+file+owner+%22.

[image: Xcode 4 and Missing File's owner]

How does one go about adding a file's owner to a storyboard.

**UPDATE**: For others who find this Stack Overflow article, its time to do Apple App's 101 again: [Creating Your First iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html). It looks like Hillegass and LeMarche have not yet caught up with the 6.0 SDK. There are no books on Amazon as of January, 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are used to nib files. Here, you just have to select the `ViewController` and set it's class in the right side of the screen, to your own custom class. About the constraints, they can be disabled by unchecking the `Use Autolayout` option in the first tab.

Comment: Ah, thanks Levi. I was not aware Apple changed things (I have not worked in Apple UI code it almost two years). Maybe it would have been a good idea to use the XIB as default rather than a new technology for unsuspecting folks :)

Comment: It's good to learn how to work with storyboards, makes your job easier after you learn how to use it properly. So have fun with it :)

Comment: Yeah, will do. One question: what is that big arrow that can be moved, but snaps back to its original place? It seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: That is the storyboard's initial view controller. In the MainStoryboard it marks your app's rootViewController. You don't have to instantiate it anymore in the app delegate.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing called `File's Owner` in story boards. File owner's job should be done by `View Controller` in your case. If you have to connect `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s, connect them with `View Controller` in the same way as you did with `File Owner` in `xib`

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add a little gotcha in xcode 5 (don't think it's in earlier versions). Basically the file's owner is called "custom class" in the identity inspector. This can be hidden! Which might confuse someone. I don't think I noticed this in v4.

[image]

[image]